# IIS Website working using localhost but not with IP Address or domain names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an issue accessing a .NET website that I have configured to use Windows authentication (Site works fine with forms authentication) . I get a 401 authorised message back every time I try accessing the site using a proper domain name or IP address but the site works as expected when accessed over localhost

[image: Below is my web.config(authentication node)]

[image: Site When accessed over Localhost]

[image: Windows authentication / ASP.net impersonation enabled in IIS]

I have made a few changes to the applicationhost.config but none has given me the desired results.
[image: Applicationhost.config]

I have also tried to items mentioned in the below URLs, but without much luck.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/896861/you-receive-error-401-1-when-you-browse-a-web-site-that-uses-integrate

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/303650/intranet-site-is-identified-as-an-internet-site-when-you-use-an-fqdn-o

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/258063/internet-explorer-may-prompt-you-for-a-password

If anyone of you have encountered this issue, please assist.

FYI, 
I have hosted this site on  AWS and for test purposes have enabled incoming https/https traffic from all IPs.
Server : Windows server 2016
IIS : IIS 10

Comment: It's been a while for me, but AFAIK, Windows Authentication essentially works with [_Windows User Accounts_, either at the machine level, or `Active Directory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/integrated-windows-authentication)

Comment: What's the substatus code? That must be checked before you move on https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Comment: Hi Lex, the sub status code is 401.2 . Looked at Microsoft support site (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942043) for this error code and none of resolutions mentioned seems to resolve my issue

Comment: Hi Ed, Yes Windows Authentication is working on localhost but not when accessed using domain name/ IP Address

Comment: "hosted this site on AWS" - did you join that machine to your Windows Domain? (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-configure-your-ec2-instances-to-automatically-join-a-microsoft-active-directory-domain/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to get this to work by switching over to Kerberos from NTLM and by 
    creating appropriate SPN entries.
    Also had to add the site to Local intranet sites

```
Below is the link that I referred.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chiranth/2014/04/17/setting-up-kerberos- 
authentication-for-a-website-in-iis/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/askie/2012/06/05/how-to-configure-internet-explorer- 
security-zone-sites-using-group-polices/

Had to additionally do this for Firefox

Enter about:config and modify a couple of entries.
network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris
network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris
network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris
Enter my domain on these settings
```